# How can I run a test separately in codeception when it has another parent class?

Tags: symfony, codeception

I am using codeception for my symfony2 project.
I want to run a functional test separately which depends on another class.
Here's my code.

```
class CheckoutFlowTestCest extends CheckoutFlowBaseCest
```

and the error I am getting is:

```
Class CheckoutFlowBaseCest not found.
```

When I run the full functional test then there's no error.

Comment: Is the right class name `checkoutFlowBaseCest` or `CheckoutFlowBaseCest`? Note that this is important during autoloading on a case-sensitive filesystem while after the class has been loaded PHP doesn't care about the case.

Comment: Can you show more code from your test class (you may be able to strip it down to a minimal skeleton that still doesn't work when executed manually)? And can you provide a more detailed error message (best would be a complete stack trace)?

Comment: Add require_once __DIR__ . '/CheckoutFlowBaseCest.php'; to the top of the file.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. @Naktibalda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question in the comment earlier.

The solution is to require_once the file of the parent class.

`require_once __DIR__ . '/CheckoutFlowBaseCest.php';`

It is necessary, because Codeception tests are not autoloaded.

Comment: It works for windows system but not for mac. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Alright I got it. In linux '/' means root so I had give the absolute path. But still I got one problem, when I run the Individual test, it works fine. But when I run the acceptance tests as a whole, it says cannot redeclare class HomePageBaseCest because I have already included it. FYI:- I am using require_once, but it doesn't work

Comment: Don't use Cest in the parent class name. If you want to run the tests twice, use 2 extending classes. Example in Codeception test suite https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.1/tests/unit/Codeception/Module/PhpBrowserTest.php